# adding user to community

Tags: salesforce, administration, salesforce-communities

I'm doing a tutorial on communities, and after setting pages and themes, i wanted to add users. The access is made from the contact object.
I setup the community, but think i should have a link here

[image]

i setup the user of a contact like this:

```
User License = Customer Community 
Profile = Customer Community User
Active = true
```

but when i try to log him in, i get: "Looks like this portal user is not a member"

I tried the same with another profile, a clone of the native Administrator profile, to which i added, in Profile Overview > App Permissions

Manage External Users = true

then, one by one, i activated all permissions, and still had that warning.

edit:

- i'm using Classic
- This is a developer licence

What am i missing?

Comment: I have no idea why this worked, but creating a new site, both links (Workspaces and Builder) work, in Setup > Digital Experiences > all sites. Can anyone anyone explain why this can happen, and why a new link solves it? You can understand this would be an unacceptable answer in a production org, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links disappeared because you killed off your own access to community (on Sysadmin, cloned profile etc). Do you remember editing this page? (sorry I had to censor some bits). If you removed System Administrator from the list of profiles - #fail.

[image: Community -> Administration-> Members page with access based on Profiles & Permission Sets]

If you can work with the new community and it's OK to have old one lying around - cool. If not - You might be able to resurrect it by exporting the community definition file, tweaking it and deploying back. I'm assuming you have some dev experience.

Prepare package.xml that contains

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Network</name>
</types>
```

Export the zip file (you don't neccessarily need developer tools, http://workbench.developerforce.com/ might be enough). Inspect the `networks/YourCommunityName.network` file. There should be a section similar to this

```
<networkMemberGroups>
    <permissionSet>Censored1Access</permissionSet>
    <permissionSet>Censored2Access</permissionSet>
    <profile>Censored User</profile>
    <profile>Admin</profile>
</networkMemberGroups>
```

Make sure "Admin" is on the list and deploy it back to org. It should give you access back and then you can add your customer community user's profile, permission set or whatever you plan to give them.

Comment: Actually, in that old community when i tried The administration link, i was asked for a login. I only edited layouts and themes.
Thanks,  I will really look in to this

Comment: So "Admin" is the contact profile i'm giving access to the community, and in <permissionSet> you are giving extra permissions to one of them, right?

Comment: Admin is technical name of System Administrator profile, you need it to restore access. And then add "Customer Community User" profile to let your Customers log in (I don't know what's the API name of that one so you might want to do it from that page's UI once you're back in). Profiles vs Permission Sets is different story. What if you'd in future have 5 communities, 5 brands you're selling and community X should be accessible only to certain users. You could clone the profile 5 times but it's maintenance nightmare, access based on perm sets might be simpler then

Comment: Sorry to bother again. I didnt go yet to re-animate the first site, im working in the second now. So, i do get the links Workspaces | Builder, in Setup > Digital Experiences > all sites, and from there, i can edit pages, themes, and page structure. But all links on top of that page, from moderation until guided setup, still ask for a login. This means i need to add users. But the documentation says it's in Administration, one of those for which i need to add a user!

Comment: i also tried to do this by adding permissions to profile, but i allways have the indication the license wont allow. Dont understand why, because the related profile is "Customer Community User"

Comment: I don't have that problem, both in my developer edition and in my job's partner community. If you're a sysadmin it should just work. Can you try in another browser? or inspect the JS error console or the network tab. You might be blocking 3rd party cookies or having some other browser-specific issues. Update your question with screenshots maybe? Got an aggressive adblock? Proxy in work network?

Comment: in the browser console, only have the usual yellow warnings from lightning. Tried in edge, and firefox, and is the same, even the warnings. Dont have adblocks, disabled all adons, in org, i dont use vpn or proxys. Funny, in a separated developer org, from work, it all works fine, with or without corporate vpn

Comment: Running out of ideas man. Consider posting at salesforce.stackexchange.com, more focused audience and we'll, it's not coding-related. Do you have MyDomain? If you do - is it 100% deployed, rolled out to users? Maybe some redirect going wrong. And if you have "high assurance session" something enabled (2nd login prompt or Authenticator app call when you enter key areas in setup, download report etc) - maybe it's messing with the community configuration attempts.

Comment: thanks. I posted here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000DGr5QAG
Gonna try there also

Comment: The solution, as in many salesforce things was simple: forget the problem, remake it the steps all over again - the 3rd time. Thanks!